# Wpf repeating lines with gradient as background

Tags: wpf

I need to make a background looks like this: [image]

I found the way to do it with `<DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile">` but it's not allow to make a gradient, because this generats many repeating squares. Maybe exists any ways to do it dynamicly, not in xaml?

Comment: How about using an `OpacityMask` with your grid? If you want a more detailed answer, you should consider sharing more code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something very similar and chose to create a grid dynamically in C#, the method was called upon on the Canvas-loaded event.

The "max_value" is the max size in pixels you want the grid to be, I set mine to 3500.

The "ScaleFactor" is the spacing in between the lines/ the size of the squares, I set mine to 15.

The "Canvas" is simply the canvas you want to apply the grid too.

I did have to extract the code and tweak it from a larger program but it should still work, but I don't have an IDE to test it currently.

```
class GridLine  //Declares a grid-line object
    {   //Declares a variety of different line lists, used for different parts of the grid.
        private List<Line> XGridline { get; set; } = new List<Line>();
        private List<Line> YGridline { get; set; } = new List<Line>();
        private Line[] Axis { get; set; } = new Line[2];

        //Used to draw the grid.
        public GridLine DrawGrid(int max_value, int scale_factor, Canvas canvas) //Draws the grid
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            while (x < max_value) // Used to draw lines from the center out to the far right.
            {
                YGridline.Add(new Line() {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    X1 = x,
                    Y1 = -max_value,
                    X2 = x,
                    Y2 = max_value
                });
                canvas.Children.Add(YGridline[YGridline.Count - 1]);
                x += scale_factor;
            }
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            while (x > -max_value) //used to draw lines from the center to the far left.
            {
                YGridline.Add(new Line() {StrokeThickness = 2,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    X1 = x ,
                    Y1 = -max_value,
                    X2 = x,
                    Y2 = max_value
                });
                canvas.Children.Add(YGridline[YGridline.Count - 1]);

                x -= scale_factor;
            }
            y = 0;
            x = 0;
            while (y < max_value)   //used to draw lines from the center to the bottom
            {
                XGridline.Add(new Line() {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    X1 = -max_value,
                    Y1 = y,
                    X2 = max_value,
                    Y2 = y
                });
                canvas.Children.Add(XGridline[XGridline.Count - 1]);
                y += scale_factor;
            }
            y = 0;
            x = 0;
            while (y > -max_value)  //Used to draw lines from the center to the top.
            {
                XGridline.Add(new Line() {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    X1 = -max_value,
                    Y1 = y,
                    X2 = max_value,
                    Y2 = y
                });
                canvas.Children.Add(XGridline[XGridline.Count - 1]);
                y -= scale_factor;
            }
            //VERTICLE LINE- Y Axis
            Axis[0] = (new Line() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), StrokeThickness = 3, X1 = 0, Y1 = -max_value, X2 = 0, Y2 = max_value });
            canvas.Children.Add(Axis[0]);

            //Horizontal line - X Axis
            Axis[1] = (new Line() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), StrokeThickness = 3, X1 = -max_value, Y1 = 0, X2 = max_value, Y2 = 0 });
            canvas.Children.Add(Axis[1]);
            return this;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
If you'd just like to have a gradient background, why don't you set the rectangles to have no/ a transparent fill then set a gradient background behind them? I would still suggest looking at my code, because depending on what you intend to do with the grid later you may find it easier to generate a grid pragmatically.